# Is it possible to link Alexa to my own web application?

Tags: web, alexa-skills-kit

Ok as part of a project I'm looking to use a skill in Alexa which I will custom make using AWS Alexa skill kit.

I basically want to build a web application in which my users could customise to their own interests then based on the interests they could ask Alexa questions about this interest? Also I am looking to do this in languages other than english... Is this possible?

Also what would be the best approach to the web app side if I want it to store real time data?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot link Alexa to web application but what you can do is, use Amazon Lex, which has voice interaction model and can connect to other applications.

Please read more about Lex [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/what-is.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use “linked_account” card. 
Login to website through OAuth 2.0 from within Alexa app.  After you login you can return a user object and query that info.